# Applescript click on a button

Tags: applescript, google, javascript, click

Is this possible to click on the button "detailed" using AppleScript (Google chrome)

**for="7cd6f428-1are-41f2-9054-c452d7fe242-view-selector-e5f5de50-634a-45bc-bf30-98e2a64676cc">Detailed**

I would usually use this for a click

```
 "document.getElementsByName('clasenamehere')[0].click();"
```

but in this situation I'm not sure how to proceed

update : I updated my reply as I didn't realised the code was hided by askdifferent text editor

that what I usually use :

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    tell tab 4 of window 1 to set myClickingbutton to execute javascript "document.getElementById('Clasenamehere').click();
"
end tell
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the entire script?

Comment: execute front window's tab 1 javascript "document.getElementsByName('namehere')[0].click();"

Comment: What is the URL of the page you are trying to action the button on, and which button is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you already know the JavaScript method for clicking on an HTML element using its class name as a selector:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('classnamehere')[0].click();
```

where `[0]` denoted the first item in the array of elements, all of whom share the same classname.  Often, it's better--at least in my mind—to try and use an element's `id`, which provides a unique attribute by which to select an element:

```
document.getElementById('idnamehere').click();
```

To run this code from *Google Chrome* by way of AppleScript, the general form looks like this:

```
    set js to "document.getElementsByClassName('classnamehere')[0].click();"

    tell application "Google Chrome" to tell ¬
        the front window to tell ¬
        the active tab to ¬
        set jsResult to execute javascript js
```

The important feature about `execute javascript` is that it must be directed to a specific `tab` in *Google Chrome*.  You can't send the command to a `window` or the `application` object.  So:

```
    tell application "Google Chrome" to ¬
        execute javascript js
```

will throw an error (even on the assumption that you had defined `js`).

The syntax can also take this form:

```
    tell application "Google Chrome" to tell front window to ¬
        set jsResult to execute of tab 1 javascript js
```

or this form:

```
    tell application "Google Chrome" to tell front window to ¬
        (execute javascript js) in front tab
```

In each of these commands, the `javascript` is being told to execute in a specific `tab`.

You haven't yet specified what *"detailed"* refers to, and when you do, I can update this answer accordingly.  Working on the assumption that it's either a `class` name or an `id` of an HTML element, you can use one of the expressions at the top and plug it straight into the code examples I gave you.  So, you might use the JavaScript method `getElementsByClassName`, which would take this form:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('detailed')[0].click();
```

where `[0]` could end up being changed to `[1]`, `[2]`, etc. depending how many other elements have this class name.  What I would then do is define my AppleScript variable `js` to hold the JavaScript command for me:

```
    set js to "document.getElementsByClassName('detailed')[0].click();"
```

then tell the `active tab` in *Chrome* to execute it:

```
    tell application "Google Chrome"
        tell active tab of window 1 to ¬
            execute javascript js
    end tell
```

The `execute` command will always return a value, even if it's just an empty string.  Therefore, if you wish, you can assign that value to a variable in AppleScript to use later in your script:

```
    set jsResult to the result
```

Or, more directly:

```
    set jsResult to execute javascript js
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, I updated my question because I didn't realised that the button name was hidden, however I approved your answer as I think there is no solution to my request due to the part encrypted name and also , even if my usually click snipped work, your seems way more clean and appropriate

Comment: Thanks.  If you're willing to share the URL, I could take a look and see if there's a way to do it.

Comment: Is there any code to just hover/move the mouse to that html element instead of clicking? I really need a way to just move the mouse to the html element instead of clicking! Thanks.

Comment: @DuyDuy You need to post that as a question on this site.  But what do you wish to achieve by hovering/moving the mouse over an html element ?  That's the first thing that needs to be known in order to be possible to help.

Comment: Dear @CJK 
I want to download some images which their url only appear when I hover my mouse over some buttons. (i.e. https://shopee.ph/Sexy-Women-Stretch-Bras-Exposure-Proof-MultiWay-Sling-sweet-lace-strap-underwear-can-be-outerwear-i.58179831.7103691378 notice the "Black" variation of the product is disable and can't be clicked, when you hover your mouse over, the image appears). I've made one with Keyboard Maestro but it's slow. It would be perfect if I can make it with Java but I know nothing about Java, please give some advices, I don't even know where to paste your script above. Thx alot